# Smart Switch in HOT Sun

Tags: outdoor, smart-switch

I have a switch on an Arizona west facing wall without protection from the hot sun (making it at least 125 to 130).  The switch, installed by the landscaper (matching standard like the flip switch here: [How do you weatherproof a light switch?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/28631/how-do-you-weatherproof-a-light-switch)) controls a small submersible pump operating the small water feature in our yard (low wattage, not dimmer adaptable).  I want to automate the switch to turn it off at night, ideally with SmartThings.  However, I have not found a smart switch or micro switch rated for that kind of temperature.  Even if I re-piped it somewhere into the shade, I am still above the normal rating of 104F.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I would double check the listings some will say 1 number on the box but a different number on the specifications page, I just looked up an outdoor passive motion sensor on line the basic info on the 1 line description 110f but the actual spec sheet said 130f / 55c  not many looked to have the full spec sheet that happens to be the first one I checked.

Comment: Yeah, you should be able to find some with higher temperature ratings.  Especially if you're looking for things meant to be used outdoors (which most smart switches are not).  For example, this one is rated for up to 122 degrees: https://www.kasasmart.com/us/products/smart-plugs/kasa-smart-wifi-outdoor-plug-kp400

Comment: It should work fine at that temp, even a lot hotter. Most electronic components can stand 80C no problem, they get soldered in after all. The big issue I can foresee is longevity. More extreme thermal cycling causes more incremental failure. Some capacitors also age quicker when hot, though they should be rated to at least 85C, and many are 105C. In short, it will work and do so safely, it just might not last as long.

Comment: Is mounting the smart-switch somewhere inside and running wires to the outdoor location an option?

Answer (score 2):

Who cares where the smart switch is physically located?  Not the smart switch.  Put it somewhere sheltered.

If you also want manual control in that location, then select a smart-switch that's designed to retrofit into old-school 3-way switch circuits.  It will expect a plain old "steam" switch as its "wired remote".  Fit a plain old switch here, run a (probably /2) cable to the smart switch location, and there you go.

Comment: The cable between the smart switch and the wired remote will likely still need to be a /3