# Wiring inside plastic shed

Tags: electrical, wiring, shed

I will be extending a GFCI-protected 15A, 120V circuit from my garage to a new plastic shed, just 6 ft away. I will be exiting the garage wall into a PVC service ell, down into the ground via 1/2" PVC conduit, and going underground to the shed via 14/2 UF cable direct-buried 12" deep (permitted by NEC 300.5 Column 4). I will enter the shed via similar means.

Inside the shed, the wiring needs are simple - a couple of outlets in convenient locations, one light, and a light switch. It will be used mostly for storage so I just need lighting and battery charging. All wiring and boxes will be surface mounted as there is no wall thickness to speak of.

Now the question. How should I wire inside the shed?

- I know I cannot run exposed, surface mounted NM or UF. Can I simply use metal handy boxes and MC cable?
- Or is the shed considered a damp location, and must I use all weatherproof boxes/switches, PVC jacketed MC cable, and threaded cord grips for all connections? (ref [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/28631/how-do-you-weatherproof-a-light-switch))

Photo of my shed and garage (new unconnected electrical service on the back of the garage is unrelated):

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you're laying UF to the shed instead of conduit? Is this all basically a temporary setup?  Also, what does your local jurisdiction deem as "subject to physical damage" for cables in unfinished spaces?

Comment: No, it’s permanent, but burying the cable instead of conduit is just slightly easier and I really don’t expect to need to run additional circuits in the future. Even if I do, it’s a short run that I can easily dig up. I haven’t had much interaction with my LAHJ so I don’t know their opinion on that. Regardless, I’m not really willing to run RMC in there...

Comment: Who is your AHJ, even?

Comment: St Paul, Minnesota

Comment: What makes you believe you can't run surface-mounted NM or UF within the shed? Physical damage concerns, or...?

Comment: Yeah that’s pretty much it, I thought MC was considered better for use in surface mounted applications but I do notice it has the same “subject to physical damage” restriction as NM, which seems odd to me.

Comment: Even if they are treated equivalently in the code, I would feel more comfortable using MC in this application I guess. Although I have never actually worked with it before.

Comment: Is EMT conduit inside the shed out of the question?  I'm comfortable working with it, and it's my go-to where physical damage might be an issue.

Comment: I guess when I said RMC in my previous comment, what I meant was any conduit (to include EMT)... mainly because I am unfamiliar with it and don’t have a bender. But, if that’s what I need to do in this situation, then I can figure it out. I still have the second question of “is this a damp location” and if so, how does that change what I can use for wiring, fittings, and boxes.

Comment: @DanA. RMC and IMC are a nightmare for this because they have to be threaded.  EMT isn't bad at all, especially if you can make do with pre-made bends.

Comment: All right, you’ve convinced me - I’ll give EMT a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The provision you're using is a bit of a fool's errand for most detached structures

The provision in the NEC you're relying on (using GFCI protection at the source end of the buried run to allow for a 12" burial depth with UF cable) is a bit of a fool's errand when feeding a detached *structure*, as it turns out.  Why? As it turns out, it's not terribly uncommon for things to develop ground faults (vs tripping breakers, even), and if something does trip the GFCI, you'd really rather not have it turn the lights out on you, especially if that something is a circular saw with a rapidly spinning blade on its business end that has a bit of momentum to it.

As a result, it's normally better to accept having to bury the cable or conduit deeper in exchange for having the lighting on a non-GFCI branch, with a GFCI receptacle or deadfront inside the shed providing protection to the receptacles there.  If you're willing to live with that limitation for now, though, given that all you're dealing with are lights and the occasional battery charger, there still are a couple of other points you'll need to keep in mind.

### You'll need some sort of disconnecting means at the structure

You'll need a disconnect where power comes into the shed.  If you want an outdoor disconnect, the easiest and cheapest way to do that is using a non-fused pullout disconnect of the type used for air conditioner outdoor units; you could also use one of those inside the shed if you don't care about anyone ever finishing the inside, or you could use a 20A key-operated lightswitch such as a Leviton 1221-2WL in an ordinary box for an indoor disconnect instead since you are only dealing with a single branch circuit.

### From there, you don't need to worry about damp

Since this shed has a reasonably functional roof on it, you don't need to treat it as a damp location per se, but there is some cause to be concerned about physical abuse given that there are no studs to speak of in such a shed, so it's much easier for boxes to pinch cables.  As a result, using MC or EMT is not an *unreasonable* decision in your situation. Note that push-fit connectors are available for both wiring methods, so you don't have to worry about setscrews, clamps, compression nuts, or such; however, you will need to use metal boxes unless you want to do all the inter-connector bonding yourself.  If you do go the cable route, by the way, look at MCI-A type cables (MC<sup>AP</sup>™ or equivalent) -- these combine the advantages of MC and AC cables in that they need neither the ground wire makeup required with traditional MC nor the "redhead" anti-short bushings required with AC cable; some products even manage to eliminate the normal assembly tape from the equation.

Comment: Thanks! This raised some good points (GFCI, disconnect) that I wasn't aware of. I agree with your point on the GFCI, unfortunately I don't have much of a choice in this instance since it's not practical for me to run a non-GFCI circuit to my shed - the entire garage is already on GFCI and it's impractical to run another circuit from upstream. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I completed a similar project last fall, running 18 ft from the house, branching off an existing 20A outdoor outlet circuit. I used leftover screws from the shed assembly to attach EMT boxes to pre-formed shelf-mounting holes, but when a heavy digging-pole fell on the boxes this spring, they ripped off the wall, lending credence to the "in case of damage" clauses requiring protection for the wiring. I'm now researching methods of reattaching the boxes.

While my circuit was originally GFCI protected at the breaker, the addition of the underground portion (liquid tight, non-metallic conduit with direct-burial 12/2 NM cable) seems to have generated a ground-fault somewhere (Dad thinks there's induced current in the ground, possibly since my ground rods are nearby?) and I was forced to use a regular breaker to get the circuit to activate. The building inspector signed off on it, but I do plan to put GFCI outlets in to protect the user, while leaving the underground supply line unprotected.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your story. If you'll take the [tour], you'll note that this is a Question & Answer board, not a general discussion forum, therefore, there really isn't room for simply sharing stories unless they're directly related to asking a new question (in which case you should use the "Ask a question" button and actually clarify what the question is) or providing an answer to a question (in which case you should [edit] this to clarify how it answers the original question).